# Have a service communicate with a widget

Tags: android, service, android-widget

I have a service I made fetch a status of something and display that status as a notification.  I would also like to display this status in a widget.  How would I communicate between a service and a widget?

Comment: This also appears to be a good resource: http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2012/10/communication-between-android-widget.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to have the Service send a broadcast when the status changes and have the widget implement a broadcast receiver.

The documentation for sending a broadcast is here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html (search that page for sendBroadcast)

The documentation for BroadcastReciver is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`AppWidgetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html) to update your widgets.

For example:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    // ...

    private void updateWidgets() {
        AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

        // Get a list of widgets to update
        int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);

        // Update the widgets
        RemoteViews updatedViews = // Create your new RemoteViews here
        widgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetIds, updatedViews);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method is to use an event bus. It's been the cleanest way I've come across for accomplishing this task. Check out Roman Nurik's Muzei project for how he does this with GreenRobot's framework.
https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/search?q=EventBus&ref=cmdform